# Browser is not closing in protractor-cucumber-framework even test failed or passed

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am using protractor 5.2. and cucumber 3.2 and protractor-cucumber-framework 6.0.0. I have used 'AfterAll', 'BeforeAll',and 'After' in my script.I have done a email sendig action by nodemailer in 'AfterAll' method.The problem is browser is not closing automatically even the test is failed or passed.And the command prompt actions are also not stopping,So i have to forcefully stop it by pressing 'ctrl' + 'C' in the command prompt for running the script again.While i am using

```
browser.close();
```

The browser get closed but still the command prompt is working.Why the browser and my command prompt is not closing automatically.How can i solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a full example of your code? Seems like you may not be waiting out any asynchronous behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

```
browser.close();
```

and

```
browser.quit();
```

Try the alternative and let me know how you get on =]

Comment: Thanks for the reply..By using above 2 options,the browser get closed but the command prompt actions not ending.I need to press 'Ctrl' +'C' to stop it and run again.

Comment: What that means is that your test is some-how still running, check you are handling all promises correctly (every single webdriver/browser command is a promise) and also ensure you don't have any browser.waits(); or something of a similar sort (basically something is still waiting to finish at the end of the tests)

Comment: As i explained, I am sending emails in 'AfterAll' method and its response is "Email sent and queued as ..". So the script continues, due to the email section?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like your 'AfterAll' method is taking some time, you should add a .catch(ex => {console.log(ex); to the end of it or set a time for it to fail in, at the moment it seems to be timing out or failing the email part. Edit: I think if you leave the test for a couple of minutes - 10 minutes it will eventually fail whatever it is trying to do

Comment: Thanks for pointing me,When i have added  setTimeout(callback, 3000); towards the end of  'AfterAll' method, browser get closed and command prompt actions stopped automatically and the Email also sent.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad i could help, have a great day!